# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object - error while updating

Tags: apex

I am trying to update a account using the below method called from an after update, after insert trigger. However I am getting an error - "Attempt to de-reference a null object" while using  Account acc = null; in the below code..AND if I use  Account acc = new Account() , I am getting the error - missing_argument id not specified in an update call in salesforce.Kindly assist.

```
   Trigger:              
   trigger testTrigg on CustObj(after insert,after update) 
   {
       for (CustObj cr1 : Trigger.new)
       {
           myClass.updateAccount(cr1);
       }
   }
 Class:
  public static myClass{
    public static void updateAccount(CustObj cr)
    {   
       List<Account> acclist = new List<Account>();
       for (Account ac : soql query)
      {               
         acclist.add(ac);
      }    
      Account acc = null;
      if (acclist.size() > 0)
      {
         acc = acclist[0];
         acc.Name = cr.Account_Name__c; 
         acc.Other_title_information__c = cr.JobTitle__c ;   
      }
     Database.SaveResult sr= Database.update(acc);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please post complete code?
what object is cr?

Comment: @NickSFDC : added the code

Comment: what is the relationship between CustObj and Account and what are you trying to achieve?
from your logic you will be able to update only first account from the acclist

Comment: @NickSFDC - CustObj and Account are in lookup relationship..yes...I dont need to bulkify as there will not be any dataload on CustObj ..users will submit records from UI only.

Comment: which is parent account or custobj?

Comment: @NickSFDC - Account is the parent..

Answer (score 1):

This change should stop the exception because it ensures that the update is only done when there is an Account value to update:

```
if (acclist.size() > 0)
{
    Account acc = acclist[0];
    acc.Name = cr.Account_Name__c; 
    acc.Other_title_information__c = cr.JobTitle__c ;   
    Database.SaveResult sr = Database.update(acc);
    // Do something with sr otherwise why assign it?
}
```

But your design is doing a query and an update per CustObj and so will break when large bulk updates of CustObj happen. Google about and apply trigger bulkification techniques.